# How to remove unneeded features and extras on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, laptop

My laptop came with preinstalled Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I can't change the OS on laptop, but Windows 7 Ultimate is much of an overhead for the computer and my intended use as well. Is there a way to remove any features, to make the installed OS closer to say Windown 7 Home Premium? I would like to speed up the laptop and get some memory freed.

Comment: You can add and remove features in the built in tool to add and remove feature but windows 7 ultimate does not use additional memory

Comment: Hi James. We usually don't delete questions  that are duplicates – they serve as anchors to help people with a similar problem.

Comment: @slhck - I understand. It seems a little unfair to me however. The question is apparently bad and got two downvotes. But It got good answers that got upvoted. So it is a bad question with good answers ? In the end I'm the one to lose rep though. It's just my observation and expressing my feeling of unjust situation. Not an attempt to criticize moderators, to be clear.

Comment: Don't worry about the reputation. It really doesn't matter that much and one upvote on a question gets you back. The thing is, you admit that there are good answers — we don't want to delete those. Also, having deleted questions may have a negative impact on your account. I can just recommend you not to worry about this all too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows built-in features does not use much memory. however you can turn the features ON or OFF by doing these steps:

1. Fist, open your Control Panel and go to Programs and features.

   [image]
2. Now at the left side of the window, you can see a link named "Turn Windows features on or off", open it.

   [image]
3. Another window will open which allows you to turn the features of or off. just mark the features you want to turn them on or unmark the features that you want to turn them off.

   [image]
4. Now, just press OK and the changes will affect.

Note that some applications need to use these features and windows may not able to do some tasks without them.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 versions have the same systems requirements with no additional system memory requirements:

> - 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor
> - 1 gigabyte (GB) RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
> - 16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
> - DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver

[Home Premium](http://www.windows7homepremium.windowsreinstall.com/about/systemrequirements.htm)
 [Ultimate](http://www.windowsreinstall.com/win7ultimate/about/systemrequirements.htm)

If your system is simply running slow you can follow the above suggestions from Amirreza Nasiri. Another might be to check/remove manufacturer bloatware, which will slow your system down.

You can do this with applications like  [The PC Decrapifier](http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/), which I have used on many occasions for just such an exercise.